# How to remove scrolling inside textarea in Extjs

Tags: extjs

I'm unable to remove scrollbar in the textarea. Data for `textarea` is coming from a json file.

```
{
        xtype: "fieldcontainer",
        layout: {
          type: 'vbox',
          align: 'stretch'
      },
        flex: 2,
        items: [{
        xtype: "textareafield",
        name: "Message",
        anchor: '100%',
        grow:true,
        scrollable: false,
        value: widgetConfig.NOTES,
        //width: "100%",
        readOnly: true,
        cls: "textareaStyles"
      }]
    }
```

scrollbar should be removed and the textarea height should auto increase

Comment: You should always provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `grow:true` in `textareafield` you have to adjust its height using `growMin` and `growMax`, in your case you are setting a height using `flex:2`
See a fiddle [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ubd)